# What is the difference between user and actor for the GitHub API issue event commented?

Tags: github-api

What is the difference between `user` and `actor` in the event issue type `commented`? [The documentation says](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/events/issue-event-types#properties-for-commented)

```
user    object  The person who commented on the issue.
actor   object  The person who generated the event.
```

Under what circumstances are they not the same? How can you be not the commenter but the one who generates the event?

Comment: As a guess, `user` might be a specific overload made available for that specific event type, whereas `actor` is a more generic property available to all event types here. That said, I don't have a source to confirm that. The documentation link specifically notes it doesn't use the same structure as the common properties, yet redefines `actor` in exactly the same way.